# Emberjs Evented vs Observers

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ember.js

Although most of the Guides and tutorials I have found relating to Ember focus heavily on using Binding, and Observers, I have also found great power in selectively using Event/Subscriber pattern via the [evented mixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Evented.html).

So before I get carried away, or begin favouring one pattern over another, ACCEPTING that they each have their own purpose:

```
//This is Object to hold the ajax request (and fire the event)
App.serverAPI = Em.Object.createWithMixins(Em.Evented, {
    responseData : '',
    init: function(){
        //Make the request on second from now
        Em.run.later(this, function(){
            this.request();
        }, 1000);
        this._super();
    },
    //The 'ajax' request function
    request: function(myData){
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url:'/echo/json/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                json: JSON.stringify({"0":"Value One", "1": "Value Two", "2": "Value Three"}),
                delay: 3
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log("Request successful ", data);
                self.set('responseData', data);
                self.trigger('responseSuccess', data);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Now One view will update using an Observer:

```
//This View gets it's value updated by Observing a changed value in an other object 
App.ObserverView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: "observer",
    displayText: "Observer waiting...",
    responseDataHandler: function(){
        //Notice how we have to get the data here, where in a listener the data could be passed
        var data = App.serverAPI.get('responseData');
        //
        //...Run functions on the data
        //
        this.set('displayText', data[0]+", "+data[1]+", "+data[2]);
        console.log('Observer displayText', this.get('displayText'));
    }.observes('App.serverAPI.responseData')
});
```

and another view will update using an Subscriber:

```
//This View gets it's value updated by subscribing to an event in an other object 
App.SubscriberView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: "subscriber",
    displayText: "Subscriber waiting...",
    init: function(){
        var self = this;
        App.serverAPI.on('responseSuccess', function(data){
            self.responseData(data);
        })
        this._super();
    },
    responseData: function(data){
        //
        //...Run functions on the data
        //
        this.set('displayText', data[0]+", "+data[1]+", "+data[2]);
        console.log('Subscriber displayText', this.get('displayText'));
    }
});
```

Now, although this example favours the observer, either pattern *could* be used, so my question is:
What are the **performance** advantages and disadvantages (if any) to using the evented mixin and What are the **performance** advantages and disadvantages (if any) to using observers?

Answer (score 3):

> What are the performance advantages and disadvantages (if any) to using the evented mixin as opposed to using observers?

To make things clear, the [`Ember.Evented`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Evented.html) mixin is not really comparable to the [`Ember.Observable`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html) mixin since they provide different functionality.

**[`Ember.Observable`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html)**

This mixin provides properties and property observing functionality, **which are core features of the Ember object model**. Properties and observers allow one object to observe changes to a property on another object. This is one of the fundamental ways that models, controllers and views communicate with each other in an Ember application, so you can't really not use it because it's in every object that extend from `Ember.Object`.

**[`Ember.Evented`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Evented.html)**

This mixin allows for Ember objects to subscribe to and emit events. You use this mixin in situation where you need some kind of custom event subscribe architecture. Using this mixing to create a data-binding mechanism is not really the point here I guess, because data-binding is already provided by the observer mechanism out of the box.

So to conclude, the choice here is not to use the observer mixin vs. the evented mixin, but rather both (if you implement the latter) in an elegant fashion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am looking for the difference in overhead so that I can make a more informed decision for scenarios where either pattern could be used as a viable solution to a problem.